# column "PO->Ledger.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to select distinct elements that are present in my main table. I have attached the code below and I am getting an error `column "PO->Ledger.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. How to solve this error?

```
findAllDistinctLedgers(options) {
const filter = {
  plain: false,
  where: { },
  include: [{
    model: db.PurchaseOrder,
    as: 'PO',
    attributes: ['ledgerId'],
    include: [{
      model: db.Ledger,
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    }],
  }],
  group: ['PO.id'],
  attributes: [],
};
if (options.excludeStatus) {
  filter.where.status = {
    [Op.ne]: options.excludeStatus,
  };
}
if (options.uamAddressIds) {
  filter.where.addressId = options.uamAddressIds;
}
return super.aggregate('PO.ledgerId', 'DISTINCT', filter);
}
```